# javascript countdown not working properly

Tags: javascript, php

I am new to javascript. I am trying to write a javascript countdown function, but it is not working when I pass a php variable to                `"var now=new Date("<?php echo $start;?>");"`. It works When I use only `"var now=new Date();"`
Thank you in advance. Here is my code...

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "ajax");
$db -> set_charset("utf8");
$query="SELECT * FROM data WHERE id=2";
$data=$db->query($query);
while ($dt=$data->fetch_assoc()) {
$start=$dt['start_time'];
$end=$dt['end_time'];
}


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title> Countdown</title>
<style type="text/css">
 body {
    background: #f6f6f6;
 }

.countdownContainer{
  position: absolute;;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform : translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 3px #ccc;
}

 .info {
  font-size: 80px;
 }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <table class="countdownContainer">
  <tr class="info">
    <td colspan="4">c   Countdown   c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="info">
    <td id="days">120</td>
    <td id="hours">4</td>
    <td id="minutes">12</td>
    <td id="seconds">22</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Days</td>
    <td>Hours</td>
    <td>Minutes</td>
    <td>Seconds</td>
    <td id="start_date"><?php echo $start;?></td>
    <td id="php_date_time"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  function countdown(){


    var now = new Date("<?php echo $start;?>");
    var eventDate = new Date("<?php echo $end;?>");
   // alert(now);
    var currentTiime = now.getTime();
    var eventTime = eventDate.getTime();

    var remTime = eventTime - currentTiime;

    var s = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
    var m = Math.floor(s / 60);
    var h = Math.floor(m / 60);
    var d = Math.floor(h / 24);

    h %= 24;
    m %= 60;
    s %= 60;

    h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
    m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
    s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

    document.getElementById("days").textContent = d;
    document.getElementById("days").innerText = d;

    document.getElementById("hours").textContent = h;
    document.getElementById("minutes").textContent = m;
    document.getElementById("seconds").textContent = s;

    setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
  }

  countdown();
</script>
```

Comment: basically the java script is running on the client side , and the php just like what you know its a server side , so no way that the javascript see the php, this is why its not working , you can solve this problem , is by passing php variables to html ( input ) , hidden type , like this http://prntscr.com/cm5jy4

Comment: so what happen is that you pass the php variables to html tag , and now javascript can read them .

Comment: @Laith I did as you suggested,but it is not counting down now :).

Comment: mhm , let me check again

Comment: does this line gave you values ? `<td id="start_date"><?php echo $start;?></td>`

Comment: @Laith yes.It looks like ` setTimeout(countdown, 1000);` not responding

Comment: mm that's weird

Answer (score 0):

your PHP only updates when your page refreshes, consequently everytime your countdown function is called it has exactly the same values:

```
function countdown(){
    var now = new Date("<?php echo $start;?>");   <--- this never changes
    var eventDate = new Date("<?php echo $end;?>"); <--- this never changes
    var currentTiime = now.getTime(); <--- this result is always the same
    var eventTime = eventDate.getTime(); <--- so is this one

    var remTime = eventTime - currentTiime; < --- obviously this one too
```